# Javascript Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a HEX to RGB colour converter and I have done all the things I think you are suppose to do and that is my JS code and HTML code

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Colour Converter</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1>Hex - RGB</h1>
    <input id="hex">
    <input id="rgb">
    <script src="Main.js"></script>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var HexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
var RGBInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHex);


function ToHex() {
  console.log("Test")
}
```

and I get this Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at Main.js:3
```

I just got started learn JavaScript and I'm fairly new

Comment: when is the JavaScript run?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Nvm, I didn't see it at the bottom of your HTML

Comment: `HexInput` must be null. You'll need to ensure that the DOM is ready.

Comment: Only thing I see that is wrong is `HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHEX());` should be `HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHex);` but that is not going to relate to that error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://prntscr.com/ic1vom

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="hex">
        <input id="rgb">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    function toHex(){
        console.log("Test");
    }

    var HexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
    var RGBInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
    HexInput.addEventListener("input", toHex());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make a few changes:

First, you need to run your script after the **entire DOM has loaded**. If you run your script before the DOM has fully loaded, then your `document.getElementById` won't be able to find the element and will return null.

Second, you also need to change `ToHEX()` to `ToHEX` in your `addEventListener`. The former was executing `ToHEX` immediately and returning nothing. The latter will **pass the function** to the `addEventListener`. **Edit:** It looks like you just updated your question to address this.

Here is the corrected code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var HexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
    var RGBInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
    HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHEX);


    function ToHex() {
      console.log("Test")
    }
});
```

Lastly, you should also move your `<script src="Main.js"></script>` line back into the header -- it doesn't need to be inserted after your HTML. Including the script after your HTML doesn't mean that it will run after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work. I fixed code order and typo error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Colour Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Hex - RGB</h1>
    <input id="hex">
    <input id="rgb">
    <script>

      function ToHex() {
        console.log("Test");
      }

      var HexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
      var RGBInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
      HexInput.addEventListener("input", ToHex);

    </script>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not true.... The script can be after the element and select it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `<script src="Main.js"></script>` and misunderstood question.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have 2 mistakes in this line

`HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHEX());`

1. the name of the method is misspelled
2. When you attach the event handler you just pass the reference to the function and not the invocation

So this would be the correct one

`HexInput.addEventListener("input",ToHex);`

Comment: And that is still wrong since it is calling it and assigning what it returns. You forgot to do what you said in #2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bassem Rabia It works

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="hex">
        <input id="rgb">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    function toHex(){
        console.log("Test");
    }

    var HexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
    var RGBInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
    HexInput.addEventListener("input", toHex);
});
```